# How to execute an URL using Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm making an application to send SMS trough VOIP providers from betamax.

To send the SMS I just need to execute the url

```
https://www.12voip.com/myaccount/sendsms.php?username=w​&password=x&from=y&to=z&text=some%20text
```

My app already creates the URL, but I can't understand how to execute. I think I have to make an http request for the same. But I don't understand it fully.

Can anyone help me on executing the url with android?

Comment: I think you need to explain this a bit better. Do you need to post to this URL and get a response back? (I'm assuming). What are you going to do with the resulting response (if there is one)?

Answer (score 9):

Android contains the [Apache Http Components](http://hc.apache.org/) in package `org.apache.http`. There you will find everything you need to call an URL with parameters.

And here you'll find the client tutorial: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/tutorial/html/

You need to do something like this:

1. Create an HttpClient (`HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();`)
2. Create a GET-method to URL (`HttpGet req = new HttpGet("url-without-params");`)
3. Add parameters to method (`req.setParams(params);`)
4. Execute method using client (`HttpResponse res = client.executeMethod(req);`)
5. Check response (`res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();`)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of what you are trying to do, but the answer is use the [Apache Http Client which is included in android](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html).

[Here's the tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/tutorial/html/).